# Coverity tool fails in freebsd 10.1 OS, facing warnings

Tags: coverity

We are already using coverity on our code-base over freebsd 9.1. But, now when we upgraded the freebsd 9.1 to freebsd 10.1  OS and ran the coverity tool we are facing the warning.
I compared "cc" in 9.1, it uses gcc compiler whereas in freebsd 10.1 we changed to clang compiler. so I tried the cov-configuration with "cc" has clang config like below but still Im facing same warning
**cov-configure --template --compiler cc --comptype clangcc**

Commands executed:
export CC="cc -DMALLOC_STUB"
**cov-build --dir main_proxyresult gmake prox**
*Coverity Build Capture version 7.0.2 on FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE amd64

Internal version numbers: 8c35bb7bf8 p-fresno-push-17316.501

HELLO new coverity/cov/bin/1001000/libcapture-freebsd64-x86_64.so

HELLO new coverity/cov/bin/10/libcapture-freebsd64-x86_64.so

HELLO new coverity/cov/bin//var/run/ld-elf-1001000.so.hints/libcapture-freebsd64-x86_64.so

HELLO new coverity/cov/bin//var/run/ld-elf-10.so.hints/libcapture-freebsd64-x86_64.so

**[WARNING] Build command gmake prox exited with signal 11 (SIGSEGV). Please verify that the build completed successfully.

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.

Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.**
For more details, please look at:

    main_proxyresult/build-log.txt*

Please let me know to overcome the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gmake` command is segfaulting. I see some fairly interesting output where there appears to be a customization that's detecting when `LD_PRELOAD` is used to inject shared objects. I suspect there's an incompatibility between this customization and Coverity's build capture libraries.

Comment: I havent set LD_PRELOAD path . It is segfault and generated the sh.core with bt like below  `$ gdb /bin/sh sh.core                                                                                        #0  0x000000004487a040 in __tls_get_addr () from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000004487a040 in __tls_get_addr () from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#1  0x00000000448787f9 in .text () from /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? () `                                                     please let me know to overcome the issue.

Comment: You may not have set `LD_PRELOAD`, but there's something on your system that's monitoring `LD_PRELOAD` and prints those messages; they aren't coming from Coverity. It's possible it's a debug setting in the FreeBSD kernel, libc, etc. Since I don't have access to your system, it's impossible for me to eliminate an incompatibility between Coverity and whatever is issuing those messages.

Comment: Coverity uses LD_PRELOAD to monitor what the native build is doing, so if that's conflicting with something in the OS, then that would explain your build failing when running under cov-build.  Open a support case with Coverity/Synopsys to get this resolved.